# How to avoid ? in the .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^some_text/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ name_folder/a=?&b=?&
```

If I want to add more parameters after the third slash I want to add `?` else the parameter is not considering. Just like `http://some_domain/some_text/a/b/?c=123&d=123` and it is not working when I use like this `http://some_domain/some_text/a/b/c=123&d=123` the `c` and `d` parameters are not working.

Comment: Please be more precise in your question what you actually want to do. Something like `http://example.com/some_text/a/b/c=123&d=123` is invalid as URL, `http://example.com/some_text/a/b/?c=123&d=123` is valid. So the question is why it is "not working" for you. So what do you actually mean by "is not working"?

Comment: http://example.com/some_text/a/b/c=123&d=123
Is there a way to make this work?
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Again: this depends on what you mean by "work" and what that URL is actually meant to express.

Comment: I want to make the url work as below using the .htaccess file since without the "?" the url looks clean 
http://example.com/some_text/a/b/c=123&d=123

Comment: The issue is that `=` and `&` are not valid characters in a URL, you'd have to `urlencode()` them. The result `http://example.com/some_text/a/b/c%3D123%26d%3D123` can hardly be called "looking clean"...

Comment: Most frameworks use the following format: `/path/to/page/param1/value1/param2/value2`.

Answer (score 0):

It is still unclear what you actually want to achieve *precisely*, your question stays vague despite my effort in the comments to get something more specific from you...

However I could imagine this is what you might be looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?some_text/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /folder/index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [L]
```

This will internally rewrite

> http://example.com/some_text/a/b/123/123

to the internal resource

> http://example.com/folder/index.php?a=a&b=b&c=123&d=123

So your "clean looking" URLs would follow that scheme:

> http://example.com/some_text/$a/$b/$c/$d

There are other options, this is just a suggestion. It is simple and robust, but requires to always have exactly 4 arguments present. Take it as a suggestion and work from there to find a solution for your specific situation which is still unclear to us.